# How to update information into database wpf

Tags: c#, .net, sql, wpf

I want to use the following code to update when a button is clicked. But I want to update the `additionalInformation` only. How would I go about doing this?

```
   public static void Update(Resident resident, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction                  transaction)
{
    StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
    SqlCommand command;

    sqlString.Append("UPDATE [Resident] SET ");
    sqlString.Append("title = @title, ");
    sqlString.Append("firstName = @firstName, ");
    sqlString.Append("surname = @surname, ");
    sqlString.Append("dateOfBirth = @dateOfBirth, ");
    sqlString.Append("photo = @photo, ");
    sqlString.Append("doctorID = @doctorID, ");
    sqlString.Append("roomID = @roomID, ");
    sqlString.Append("allergies = @allergies, ");
    sqlString.Append("additionalInformation = @additionalInformation ");
    sqlString.Append("WHERE residentID = @residentID ");
    command = new SqlCommand(sqlString.ToString(), connection);
    if ((transaction != null)) command.Transaction = transaction;

    command.Parameters.Add("@residentID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = resident.ResidentID;
    command.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Helper.GetValue(resident.Title);
    command.Parameters.Add("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Helper.GetValue(resident.FirstName);
    command.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Helper.GetValue(resident.Surname);
    command.Parameters.Add("@dateOfBirth", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Helper.GetValue(resident.DateOfBirth);
    command.Parameters.Add("@photo", SqlDbType.Image, 2147483647).Value = Helper.GetValue(resident.Photo);
    command.Parameters.Add("@doctorID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = resident.Doctor.DoctorID;
    command.Parameters.Add("@roomID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = resident.Room.RoomID;
    command.Parameters.Add("@allergies", SqlDbType.NText).Value = resident.Allergies;
    command.Parameters.Add("@additionalInformation", SqlDbType.NText).Value = resident.addtionalInformation;
    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (!(rowsAffected == 1))
    {
        throw new Exception("An error has occurred while updating Resident details.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass one more parameter indicating that you want to update only `addidionalInformation`, for example:

```
public static void Update(Resident resident, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, bool updateOnlyAdditionalInformation)
{
    StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
    SqlCommand command;

    sqlString.Append("UPDATE [Resident] SET ");

    if (!updateOnlyAdditionalInformation)
    {
      sqlString.Append("title = @title, ");
      sqlString.Append("firstName = @firstName, ");
      sqlString.Append("surname = @surname, ");
      sqlString.Append("dateOfBirth = @dateOfBirth, ");
      sqlString.Append("photo = @photo, ");
      sqlString.Append("doctorID = @doctorID, ");
      sqlString.Append("roomID = @roomID, ");
      sqlString.Append("allergies = @allergies, ");
    }

    sqlString.Append("additionalInformation = @additionalInformation ");
    sqlString.Append("WHERE residentID = @residentID ");
    command = new SqlCommand(sqlString.ToString(), connection);
    if ((transaction != null)) command.Transaction = transaction;

    command.Parameters.Add("@residentID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = resident.ResidentID;
    command.Parameters.Add("@additionalInformation", SqlDbType.NText).Value = resident.addtionalInformation;

    if (!updateOnlyAdditionalInformation)
    {
      command.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Helper.GetValue(resident.Title);
      command.Parameters.Add("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Helper.GetValue(resident.FirstName);
      command.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Helper.GetValue(resident.Surname);
      command.Parameters.Add("@dateOfBirth", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Helper.GetValue(resident.DateOfBirth);
      command.Parameters.Add("@photo", SqlDbType.Image, 2147483647).Value = Helper.GetValue(resident.Photo);
      command.Parameters.Add("@doctorID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = resident.Doctor.DoctorID;
      command.Parameters.Add("@roomID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = resident.Room.RoomID;
      command.Parameters.Add("@allergies", SqlDbType.NText).Value = resident.Allergies;
    }

    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (!(rowsAffected == 1))
    {
        throw new Exception("An error has occurred while updating Resident details.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how would I add this to a button click event handler?

Comment: Not user how your button handler looks like (you can add it to your original post) but call it like this: `Update(resident, connection, null, true);`

Comment: I get this error: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction'

Comment: Either you did not changed method signature (just copy-paste mine) or you are missing one argument from call (i use 4 `resident, connection, null, true` you probably passed 3)

Comment: I got another error : The name 'connection' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Can you post how you called that method originally? Because I just used markup that you should change to your needs. I do not know how your fields looks like etc.

Comment: I got it to work by doing :  Resident hello = new Resident();
            ResidentData.Update(hello);  But then I got another error On : command.Parameters.Add("@doctorID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = resident.Doctor.DoctorID; Saying: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: That is different method signature that you posted. Is there in your `ResidentData` class methods like `Update(Resident resident)` and `Update(Resident resident, SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction)`?

Comment: The Update method takes parameters (Resident resident)